# Create iso/image/installation from Windows XP-installation

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virtual-machines, disk-image

I'm using VMware and want to create a virtual machine with Windows XP. For this I want to use the Windows XP-installation of another computer, I don't have the cd, so I want to create a iso/image (or whatever) of this Windows-installation. How can I do this?

Comment: Don't forget, Windows XP is no longer supported, it's past time to move on.

Comment: Sure. But I only want to test some issues for a application only working with Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to use Vmware Converter (http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) to create an image so you can use it on other Vmware Platforms (vSphere, Workstation,...).

There are a lot of guides on the net about how to use the software. This one may help you:

http://www.petri.co.il/virtual_convert_physical_machines_to_virtual_machines_with_vmware_converter.htm

Regards,

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try to download VMware Converter but I'm asked to create an account and fill in name, organization, phone number and so on. It's only for private use. Suggestions?

Comment: Just register with a private account. You can use that account later to test new Vmware products.

Comment: This one? https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=converter#tab_register

Comment: You should find the download link under License & download. You need to have logged in into your account to get the download link.